# How to hide a row when a column has been editied.

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a inventory list that staff will be able to view and make requests for those items. I have a "person or group" column in the inventory list that the user will add their name when making a request. How can I hide that item row or prevent other from making requests on the same item with a formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a column setting called "Enforce unique values" that only allows one item to have specific data in the list.

For example if you apply this to a people picker column in a list you can only have one item in that list with your name. When users add other items and choose your name they will be notified that that value was already used.

This option is available on other types of columns such as choice menu to choose from.

This does not hide but it limits new data to be duplicated in a list if used correctly.

Comment: This won't work in the case where you try to assign same name to different items. OP is instead looking to prevent different names for the same item.

Answer (score 2):

Create a default view that only shows inventory items where Person field is blank. this way when someone goes in and adds their name to an item, it disappears from the view.

Comment: I have created a new view, but I am confused on how I would display the list of items and hide them when someone enters their name. Does it require a formula column?

Comment: @wisenhiemer In your new view, set up a filter to only show items where Person field is blank. These means that users will only be able to see unfilled inventory items. The second someone enters their name into these items, since the person field is no longer blank....it won't show on the view (effectively hiding them).